# Is it possible to specify linker options from code?

Tags: c, linker, clang

I wonder if it's possible to specify a linker option from code? Compilers allow `#pragma` directives to suppress warnings; how far can we extend this?

Comment: Succinctly, "No".

Comment: **Why do you ask?** Please **edit your question** to motivate it and give a lot more details. Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(I'm considering implicitly linking on Linux systems and using the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler; you probably could adapt the answer to your OS)</sup>

No, it is impossible to specify link options in code, and notice that the linker is working on object files (not on individual functions inside them).

However, your [build procedure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_build) could extract linker options from the source code. For instance, if you have a directory with many single-source programs (that is, `aa.cc` C++ source file compiled into `aa.bin` executable, `bb.cc` compiled into `bb.bin`, etc) you might have a [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) mentioning

```
%.bin: %.cc
       $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $(shell awk /Link:/{print $2} $<) $^ -o $@
```

and in `aa.cc` a comment like:

```
/* the link option is
   Link: -lfoo
 */
```

BTW, you might also have some [GCC plugin](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins.html) which [registers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gccint/Plugins-attr.html) and handles your specific `#pragma`; If you use `clang` instead of `gcc`  you can also have some [Clang plugin](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangPlugins.html); that new pragma could add something in a common Sqlite database which is later used at link time.

So you could do sophisticated things, but I would simply suggest to have your own [`make` rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Rules.html) to handle your linking.

Comment: Thank you for your help, the XY problem makes sense. I was thinking about if it's possible to implement a testing framework that generate different program entry point based on macros, since it's impossible, I will do it in with script :)

Comment: Don't forget that it is possible to use metaprogramming techniques; you could have some script generating C or C++ code, or test cases, or compilation or linking commands.